# Grabbing extended properties from SQL Server into DataTable

Tags: sql-server-2008, ado.net, extended-properties

I have a view called `PersonOverview` which has a bunch of columns; it's a totally normal view, nothing special about it.

I added an extended property called `FlexGridHide` with a value of `1` to the `DatenbereichCD` column of that view using.

```
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty 
        @name = N'FlexGridHide', 
        @value = N'1', 
        @level0type = N'SCHEMA', @level0name = dbo, 
        @level1type = N'VIEW',  @level1name = vPersonOverview,
        @level2type = N'COLUMN', @level2name = DatenbereichCD;
```

I can find that extended property in SQL Server - no problem - it's there.

But when I load data from the view into a `DataTable`, I'm obviously not able to actually read out that extended property:

```
string sqlSelect = @"SELECT TOP 5 DatenbereichCD FROM dbo.vPersonOverview";

DataTable personUebersicht = new DataTable();

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MYDB"].ConnectionString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlSelect, con))
using (SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
{
   dap.Fill(personUebersicht);
}

DataColumn datenbereichCD = personUebersicht.Columns["DatenbereichCD"];    
int extendedProps = datenbereichCD.ExtendedProperties.Count;
```

The connection works just fine, the query gets executed just fine, returns five rows as expected, the column is present, and everything seems fine - except I don't get any values in the `ExtendedProperties` collection - the `.Count` is always 0.

Any ideas? Is there anything I can do to actually **get** those extended properties? Connection string parameter or a property on the `SqlCommand` or something obscure?

**Update:** to the untrained ignorant, having `Extended Properties` on SQL Server columns, and `Extended Properties` on the ADO.NET `DataColumn` type sort of suggested that those SQL Server extended properties would be loaded into the ADO.NET extended properties - but that really doesn't seem to be the case - ah well.....

I ended up using a second query, as Kevin suggested - but since I need to get extended properties for both tables and views and you have to *specify* what you're looking for using the `fn_listextendedproperty` function, I instead chose to query the `sys.extended_properties` system catalog view for the information I need. This here is my query that I'm using to get the information I need about the extended properties from SQL Server:

```
SELECT 
    ep.class, ep.class_desc, ep.name, ep.value,
    SchemaName = s.name,
    ObjectName = o.name,
    ColumnName = c.Name,
    ObjectType = o.type, 
    ObjectTypeDesc = o.type_desc
FROM sys.extended_properties ep
INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON ep.major_id = o.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON ep.major_id = c.object_id AND ep.minor_id = c.column_id
```

Comment: I know that this is not optimal, but have you considered using the fn_listextendedproperty table function?

Comment: @AaronBertrand: care to post this as a "Connect" issue to Microsoft? They seem to listen to you - much more than to me anyway :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldataaccess/thread/9371cf9c-48a1-4fdc-89e5-d01fcf69e2c1) the SQL Server extended properties and the ADO.NET extended properties are not related:

> The dataColumn.ExtendedProperties is not related to the extended property of column on the SQL server backend.

It appears that you will need to resort to retrieving the extended properties in a [separate query](http://databases.aspfaq.com/schema-tutorials/schema-how-do-i-show-the-description-property-of-a-column.html).

```
DataTable personUebersicht = new DataTable();
DataTable extendedProperties = new DataTable();

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MYDB"].ConnectionString))
{
    string sqlSelect = @"SELECT TOP 5 DatenbereichCD FROM dbo.vPersonOverview";
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlSelect, con))
    using (SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        dap.Fill(personUebersicht);
    }

    string sqlProperties = @"SELECT name, value FROM ::fn_listextendedproperty(null,'user','dbo','view','vPersonOverview','column','DatenbereichCD')";
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlProperties, con))
    using (SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        dap.Fill(extendedProperties);
    }
}

// Test the results
foreach (DataRow row in extendedProperties.Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", row["name"], row["value"]));
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it seems that - against the *Principle of least surprise* - those two "things" are really totally not related.... hmmm.... having "Extended Property" on the SQL Server columns, and "Extended Property" on the ADO.NET `DataColumn` would lead some ignorants like myself to **assume** that's basically the same thing.... not so - unfortunately!

Comment: Thanks for your input - I went a slightly different route in the end (see my update to my question)

Comment: I hear you.  Who would guess that "extended properties" are not actually "extended properties"???  Anyway, I'm glad you found a solution that works for you.

Comment: And here I thought the extendedproperties would allow me to automatically supply custom metadata along with query results... sigh.  SQL Extended Properties: about as useful as tits on a bull.