# Tag SQL Server instance as DEV, TEST, STAGING, PRODUCTION etc

Tags: sql-server

We have a few SQL Server boxes and instances running, we wish our code to identify if it is running on Development, Test or Production server instance of SQL Server. Based on that we would like to code to take a certain path.

We have few choices of hard coding the SQL Server Name and Instance like

1. `Case when @@SERVERNAME= ABC/XYZ then DEV` and so on.
2. Check specific letters in Name or INSTANCE `WHEN (CHARINDEX('DEV', @@SERVERNAME, 1) > 0 )  then DEV` and so on.
3. Select type from a table:

   ```
   select @vcServerType = vcServerType 
   from master.dbo.tbl_ServerDetails
   when @vcServerType = 'DEV' and so on.
   ```

But all rely on assumption that DEV will be found or server name will contains certain letters, creating a table in database that will exist in all instances..

Should have been so much easier if only there exists a property to set/identify at instance level.. any suggestions (apart from above)

IS there a way in SQL server, where we can set some property or Tag them as DEV, TEST or Production?

Comment: I'm not always sure it's a good idea for code to know if the environment is dev or production. If you have code that runs differently in those environments, how can you be sure that your testing is accurate?

Comment: You forgot that you could just use the Registry as well to store your environment (ie, AppIsRunning key value = 1 (dev), 2 (test), 3 (production). This allows for easy debugging of code that branches based on where it is deployed--- dev,test, or production.

Comment: @DavidG it's not about much about code but configuration per environment e.g. connection string. Additionally we have scenarios where we wish to execute few scripts only on certain env.

Comment: @StarPilot You are correct but machine level descriptors do not helps as we have multiple instances on same box as well.

Comment: @NarinderSharma then go with the configuration settings at the application level or create a table to store settings. it is not safe to have the code contain settings: should you need to change the value of a parameter you would have to hunt for it in the code and possibly make a new release. to change a setting??? O_o  imho not a godd idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a tab named "Extended Properties" on the Database Level in it's properties.

[You can set them with sys.sp_addextendedproperty](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190243(v=sql.105).aspx)

And read them for instance in ADO.NET like the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331336/grabbing-extended-properties-from-sql-server-into-datatable) Shows.

Edit: I didn't really see that you asked about a tag on the instance-level or maybe on Server Level. Sorry for not directly addressing that. But you should be able to achieve what you wish for through the properties on DB-Level, shouldn't you?

Answer (score 0):

Following up the advise above, yes extended properties are fabulous solution.

```
    use master
    go

    EXEC sp_addextendedproperty
         @name = 'Environment'
      , @value = 'Development'

    SELECT [value] AS [EnvironmentType]
    FROM [sys].[extended_properties] AS [ep]
    WHERE [ep].[class_desc] = 'DATABASE'
      AND [ep].[name] = 'Environment';
```